# Laravel 5.4 font-awesome not displaying

Tags: laravel

Just started using laravel 5.4 and am stock with this issue of icons not showing or displaying on my project.  Fonts such as the font-awesome even bootstrap icons aren't displaying any help?
Will be really glad if anyone could help out

Comment: Copy all your assets (i.e. css, js)  into public folder of laravel app, if you could shows the code and your asset folders here, we can help more.

Comment: Maybe you are using html code to call css and js library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using blade syntax to call you js and css library ?

Comment: I copied the font-awesome css into my laravel public repository.

Comment: I mean are you using blade or html syntax to call you library ? you library can be external or interne it doesn't matter but make sure your are  connecting to internet if you are using external library and working in your local environment.

Comment: Thanks. I used the blade library and it worked fine. Thanks guys

Comment: its will be nice if you tag my answer as rigth :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using webpack.mix.js and Laravel 5.5..

- Ensure you've included font-awesome via NPM `npm install font-awesome --save-dev`
- Pull font-awesome into the resources/assets/sass/app.scss file `@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";`
- Recompile assets via `npm run dev`

There's some automagic behind the scenes I believe which copies required fonts to the public directory, see below:

[image: Laravel 5.5 npm run dev example]